# NSInvalidArgumentException in windowsWithKeyWindow running KIF test from XCODE

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using KIF 3.3.0 and XCODE 7.1.  I've setup KIF using cocoaPods using https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF#installation-with-cocoapods

As soon as I run my tests in XCODE (CMD-U), it tried to run my KIF test but it doesn't launch the application (instead it opens another empty window) which leads to the exception below because the window is nil.  But I'm not sure what configuration I'm missing.  I know this must be a setup issue.  I've already looked at the SO answers [All KIF test steps are throwing the same error, what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538958/all-kif-test-steps-are-throwing-the-same-error-what-am-i-doing-wrong) and others but they don't tell you what's wrong in the configuration.  What am I missing?

Please someone help.

```
.../Pods/KIF/Additions/UIApplication-KIFAdditions.m:110: error:
-[Mobile_iOSUITests testSuccessfulRegistration] : failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil" (    
0   CoreFoundation    0x000000010e6d1f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165    
1   libobjc.A.dylib    0x000000010e14bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48     
2   CoreFoundation       0x000000010e598ea5 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 901   
3   Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011808fb41
-[UIApplication(KIFAdditions) windowsWithKeyWindow] + 193   
4   Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011808edc4
-[UIApplication(KIFAdditions) accessibilityElementWithLabel:accessibilityValue:traits:] + 180   
5   Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011808e06e
+[UIAccessibilityElement(KIFAdditions) accessibilityElementWithLabel:value:traits:error:] + 158     
6   Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011808db32
+[UIAccessibilityElement(KIFAdditions) accessibilityElement:view:withLabel:value:traits:tappable:error:] + 178  
7   Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011807f9ca
__83-[KIFUITestActor waitForAccessibilityElement:view:withLabel:value:traits:tappable:]_block_invoke
+ 106   
8   Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011807c067 -[KIFTestActor tryRunningBlock:complete:timeout:error:] + 167    
9   Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011807c379 -[KIFTestActor runBlock:complete:timeout:] + 137     
10  Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011807c484 -[KIFTestActor runBlock:complete:] + 148     
11  Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011807c560 -[KIFTestActor runBlock:] + 64   
12  Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011807f901 -[KIFUITestActor waitForAccessibilityElement:view:withLabel:value:traits:tappable:] + 337    
13  Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011807f731
-[KIFUITestActor waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:value:traits:tappable:] + 209    
14  Mobile-iOSUITests               0x000000011807f283 -[KIFUITestActor waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:] + 99    
15  Mobile-iOSUITests        0x0000000118079740 -[Mobile_iOSUITests testSuccessfulRegistration] + 144
```

Comment: Anybody? Please help.  I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by a developer on github KIF https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/732
Basically issue was when you create your test target for KIF, make sure to choose IOS Unit Testing Bundle and NOT IOS UI Testing Bundle.